# Calling Java webdynpro from JSP or Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, webdynpro

Is it possible to call SAP Java web dynpro application from JSP or Java Servlet  in another system ? If possible please advise how.

-Vipin.

Answer (score 0):

This has been achieved by using iframe tag and application url of web dynpro application as src.

Comment: So could you please elaborate your answer and place your snippet of code?